# Checking multiple variables' values to make sure they all match

Tags: javascript, variables, string-matching

How do I efficiently check to see if multiple variables' values all match? The following function should return true if they match and false if they don't:

```
function projectIsLocked (data) {
    if (data.ArchiveSnapshotID === data.CurrentSnapshotID === data.LiveSnapshotID) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I thought I could just use `if (data.ArchiveSnapshotID === data.CurrentSnapshotID === data.LiveSnapshotID)` but it doesn't seem to work.

Ideas for something simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are just 3 comparisons , then this should be enough.

```
function projectIsLocked (data) {
    var archive = data.ArchiveSnapshotID;
    var current = data.CurrentSnapshotID;
    var live = data.LiveSnapshotID;

    return (archive === current && current === live)
}
```

Comment: +1 You can also get rid of the `if` statement since the result of the comparison will always be boolean. `return archive === current && current === live`

Comment: lot better .. Thx.. Didn't think in those terms

Answer (score 1):

Why not push them all to an array. This way you can use as many.

```
function check_for_equal_array_elements(my_array){
  if (my_array.length == 1 || my_array.length == 0) {
     return true;
  }
  for (i=0;i<my_array.length;i++){
     if (i > 0 && my_array[i] !== my_array[i-1]) {
       return false;
     }
  }
  return true;
}

//Example:
var my_array = [];
my_array.push(5);
my_array.push(5);

// will alert "true"
alert("all elements equal? "+check_for_equal_array_elements(my_array));

my_array.push(6);
// will alert "false"
alert("all elements equal? "+check_for_equal_array_elements(my_array));
```

Comment: Recommendation: use `!==` in comparing `my_array[i] !== my_array[i-1]`, so that `"5"` and `5` don't count as equal (since the OP specifies a triple equals in the question). (Also, +1)

Comment: These values won't be stored in an array. They're just local variables.

Comment: Technically, the way the author has phrased the question, you are adding an unnecessary step because he's attempting to compare properties of the same object.  You can use a for loop to iterate over the properties of the object to compare them.

Comment: Yeah pushing them to an array is another option.

Comment: @PlanB if you have a solution post it, not just Comment.

Comment: @KingKongFrog I'm not trying to argue, just offering a way to optimize your solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is, that a part of the logical expression is evaluated and then compared, so  `data.ArchiveSnapshotID === data.CurrentSnapshotID` evaluated to "true" and `data.LiveSnapshotID` is checked against true, which you can see here (`LiveSnapshotID` was changed to boolean `true`):

```
function projectIsLocked (data) {
    if (data.ArchiveSnapshotID === data.CurrentSnapshotID === data.LiveSnapshotID) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

var data = { ArchiveSnapshotID: "foo", CurrentSnapshotID: "foo", LiveSnapshotID: true };
alert(projectIsLocked (data));
```

You might want to use something like this, which is quite extensible for even more properties.

```
function projectIsLocked (data) {
    var props = ["ArchiveSnapshotID", "CurrentSnapshotID", "LiveSnapshotID"];

    for (var i = 1; i < props.length; i++) 
    {
        if (data[props[i]] !== data[props[i - 1]])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```